# Difference between maximum and minimum of same set

Tags: notation, maxima-minima

I was wondering if there is a property to express the difference between the max and min of the same set of elements:
$$\max(x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n) - \min(x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n)$$
where $x_i$ are all positive reals.

Is there a property to state the same thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "a property"? Do you mean *a name*? or, *a notation*?

Comment: I mean an equivalant expression. Something more compact than the one I stated in the original post. For example, $\max(a,b) + \min(a,b) = a+b$

Comment: OK. Not likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n\geq 2$:

$$ \max  _{1\leq i<j\leq n} |x_i-x_j| .$$

---

For $n=2$ this is simply

$$|  x_1-x_2|.$$

Comment: great, thanks! :)